# Criação de um Carrinho de Compras

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou querendo criar um Carrinho, onde nele tenha os Produtos que eu vou vender, a quantidade e o valor total.
Alguém tem uma ideia de como posso começar o desenvolvimento?

Só para esclarecimento, segue a minha classe de Produto, que parte de um Cardápio:

```
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Produto")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do produto deve ter entre 5 a 20 caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a descrição do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Descrição")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do produto deve ter entre 5 a 50 caracteres")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o valor do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Valor R$")]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    //relacionamentos
    public int RestauranteID { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurante Restaurante { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Eu já prefiro guardar no localstorage do browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara, em MVC eu crio dados temporários que são salvos na sessão. Vou dar um exemplo de um sistema que eu fiz para uma haburgueria levando em consideração seu Model:

**Dados Temporários**

Aqui você irá armazenar na sessão os dados dos pedidos. Vamos supor que um pedido seja uma lista de produtos que o usuário escolheu

```
using System.Web;
using Hamburgueria.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Hamburgueria
{
    public class DadosTemporarios
    {
        const string CHAVE_PEDIDOS = "PEDIDOS";

    internal static void ArmazenaPedidos(Produto produtoDoPedido)
    {
        List<Produto> pedidos = RetornaPedidos() != null ?
            Retornapedidos() : new List<Produto>();

        pedidos.Add(produtoDoPedido);
        HttpContext.Current.Session[CHAVE_PEDIDOS] = pedidos;
    }

    internal static void RemovePedidos(int id)
    {
        List<Produto> pedidos = RetornaPedidos();
        pedidos.RemoveAt(id);
        HttpContext.Current.Session[CHAVE_PEDIDOS] = pedidos;
    }

    internal static void RemovePedidos()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[CHAVE_PEDIDOS] = new List<Produto>();
    }

    internal static List<Produto> RetornaPedidos()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[CHAVE_PEDIDOS] != null ?
            (List<Produto>)HttpContext.Current.Session[CHAVE_PEDIDOS] : null;
    }
}
 }
```

Certo, mas e agora? Simples! no seu Controller você só precisa usar os métodos dessa clase para salvar na sessão, desse jeito:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarProdutoAoCarrinho(Produto produto)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
                DadosTemporarios.ArmazenaPedidos(produto);
            else{
                ///TODO
            }

            return View("Index", produtos);
        }
```

Na sua view tu ainda pode chamar o método que retorna os ítens do carrinho para mostrar quantos tem ainda :)

No caso desse meu projeto eu fui pouco mais longe com o banco de dados. No meu caso é apenas um restaurante mas você pode mudar isso fácil. Segue o esquema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só seguir nesse caminho que tu consegue fácil :)
Valeu

Comment: No caso, os Produtos ficariam em uma Index de Pedidos? Uma lista, no caso?

Comment: O que seria esse:
   const string CHAVE_PEDIDOS = "PEDIDOS"; ?

Comment: Sim. Se você for usar database Fist é só fazer uma scaffold normal e criar toda CRUD só clicando com botão direito. Ele já cria as views também. Ahh, no final do insert (quando o cliente finalizar o pedido) limpe os dados da sessão com "Session.Clear();"
Esse Const string é uma chave que eu crio e uso em cada Session do meu contexto atual. Se eu quiser guardar dois dados diferentes (ex. Pedidos e usuário atualmente logado) eu precisaria de outra chave

Comment: No caso, o Cliente no meu programa (logado através de uma Session), irá fazer a compra. O que devo colocar ali dentro?

Comment: coloca qualquer coisa como chave, cara...
depois só seguir o exemplo que eu dei para fazer o armazenamento desse usuário.
Marca a resposta como certo, namizade :)

Comment: Na verdade, ficou bem vago. Levando em consideração que irei utilizar uma tabela de pedido ainda, além da tabela de produto. E ainda preciso clicar no produto pra ele entrar na lista de pedidos.

Comment: como ficou vago? eu a sua pergunta foi "como posso começar o desenvolvimento" e eu te dei um banco de dados e todo o esquema para salvar na sessão de forma boa. tu quer que eu desenvolva para você não vai aprender nada

Comment: Mas como eu irei adicionar os itens no Carrinho através de um botão, dentro do cardápio, por exemplo?

Comment: Cara, aí tu tem que criar um formulário e criar um botão de input que vai receber o post. lá tu faz como eu disse na resposta:             `if(ModelState.IsValid)
                DadosTemporarios.ArmazenaPedidos(produto);`